# Aggregate grouping with two keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a following collection in mongodb :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 183,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "Product Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0056"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 185,
        "weekofyear" : 23,
        "productcount" : 2,
        "count" : 23,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "Product Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 182,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 1,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "11",
        "filtername" : "Sub Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0022"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 186,
        "weekofyear" : 26,
        "productcount" : 25,
        "count" : 25,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "11",
        "filtername" : "Sub Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947b0032"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 7,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 182,
        "weekofyear" : 26,
        "productcount" : 23,
        "count" : 12,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "11",
        "filtername" : "Sub Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5348c108b09c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 170,
        "weekofyear" : 26,
        "productcount" : 235,
        "count" : 1,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "Sub Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("658c108b209c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 185,
        "weekofyear" : 26,
        "productcount" : 235,
        "count" : 1,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "12",
        "filtername" : "price Range"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c022c947a0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 181,
        "weekofyear" : 26,
        "productcount" : 235,
        "count" : 1,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "12",
        "filtername" : "price Range"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("213c108b209c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 184,
        "weekofyear" : 27,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 27,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "12",
        "filtername" : "price Range"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c082c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 183,
        "weekofyear" : 26,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 13,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "12",
        "filtername" : "price Range"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5589108b209c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 184,
        "weekofyear" : 21,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 21,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "12",
        "filtername" : "price Range"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558a108b209c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 185,
        "weekofyear" : 26,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 16,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "13",
        "filtername" : "price Range"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c118b209c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 170,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "13",
        "filtername" : "price Range"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c033c947b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 182,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 1,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "14",
        "filtername" : "brand"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b909c033c947b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 188,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 1,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "brand"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c033c937b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 162,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 1,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "14",
        "filtername" : "brand"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c101b209c033c937b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2014,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 363,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "brand"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c101b299c033c937b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 183,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "16",
        "filtername" : "brand"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c101b199c033c937b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 183,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "brand"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c101b199c033c939b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 185,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "18",
        "filtername" : "brand"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c101b199c044c937b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 163,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "11",
        "filtername" : "brand"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c191b199c033c939b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2014,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 178,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "concern"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c198b909c033c947b0026"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 188,
        "weekofyear" : 24,
        "productcount" : 1,
        "count" : 24,
        "position" : "2","
            "productsclickedi"d" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "14"",
        "filtername" : "c"oncern"
}                "
"
"
{                "
    "_id" : ObjectId(""558c118b310c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero st"orm tour",
        "year" : 2015,   "
            "month" : 6,     "
            "day" : 1,       "
            "hour" : 17,     "
            "dayofyear" : 188,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "16",
        "filtername" : "concern"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("539c118b310c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 4,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "18",
        "filtername" : "concern"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c118b310c022c947b1145"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 4,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 21,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "18",
        "filtername" : "concern"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c992b310c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 1,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 2,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "Product Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c118b123c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2014,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 364,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 32,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "17",
        "filtername" : "Product Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c223c310c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2014,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 365,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "14",
        "filtername" : "Product Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c220c310c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 196,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "Product Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c108b209c311c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 195,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "Product Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c999b209c311c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 195,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "19",
        "filtername" : "Product Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c999c310c022c947b0055"),
        "term" : "aero storm tour",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 196,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "2",
        "productsclickedid" : "7156",
        "sessionid" : "14"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c220c310c022c749b0055"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 194,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "15",
        "filtername" : "Product Category"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c730c310c022c749b0055"),
        "term" : "aero",
        "year" : 2015,
        "month" : 6,
        "day" : 1,
        "hour" : 17,
        "dayofyear" : 195,
        "weekofyear" : 22,
        "productcount" : 0,
        "count" : 22,
        "position" : "autocomplete",
        "productsclickedid" : "8156",
        "sessionid" : "10",
        "filtername" : "Product Category"
}
```

I am trying to find the **count** of **term** and **filtername** in the specified date-range.

**My query** :

```
db.filterclick.aggregate(

    {$match:
       {$or :[
             { $and :[{dayofyear:{ $gte : 1, $lte : 4 }},{year : 2015}]},
             { $and :[{dayofyear:{ $gte : 363, $lte : 365 }},{year : 2014}]}
             ]
       }
    },
    {$group:{
        _id: "$term",
        _id: "$filtername",
        term :{$first :"$term"},
        filtername :{$first : "$filtername"},

            totalcount : {
                $sum : "$count"
            }
        }
     },
     {
      $sort : {totalcount : -1}
     },{
    $project: {
    "term" : 1,
    "filtername" : 1,
    "totalcount" : 1,   
    "_id" : 0
    }
    }

)
```

**Output** :

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "term" : "aero storm tour",
            "filtername" : "Product Category",
            "totalcount" : 56
        }, 
        {
            "term" : "aero storm tour",
            "filtername" : "concern",
            "totalcount" : 43
        }, 
        {
            "term" : "aero",
            "filtername" : "brand",
            "totalcount" : 24
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

**Desired Output :**

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "term" : "aero storm tour",
            "filtername" : "Product Category",
            "totalcount" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "term" : "aero storm tour",
            "filtername" : "concern",
            "totalcount" : 44
        }, 
        {
            "term" : "aero",
            "filtername" : "brand",
            "totalcount" : 24
        },
        {
            "term" : "aero",
            "filtername" : "concern",
            "totalcount" : 21
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

The query should aggregate and calculate the count based on combination on term and filtername , but it doesn't.

I know my query is not creating combination of filtername and term. How to do it?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). The `_id` needs to be a composite key. How you are writing it you are "overwriting" the value of `_id` so it only groups on `$filtername`:

```js
  { "$group": {
      "_id": { "term": "$term", "filtername": "$filtername" },
      "term": { "$first":"$term" },
      "filtername": { "$first": "$filtername" },
      "totalcount" : { "$sum": "$count" }
  }}
```

So `_id` is the "grouping key" and like all keys in BSON documents *"there can only be one"*. That is why the totals are not coming out as the "combination" of those two fields in your grouping.

Comment: Yeah, Works .Thanks !!